# hibernatetemplate clear ehcache?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, ehcache

```
<ehcache>
    <cache name="query.ContactInfoList"
        maxElementsInMemory="200"
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    />
</ehcache>

public List getContactInfoList(){
    hibernateTemplate.setCacheQueries(true);
    hibernateTemplate.setQueryCacheRegion("query.ContactInfoList");
    List list = hibernateTemplate.find("from AdoContactInfo a where active = 1");
    hibernateTemplate.setCacheQueries(false);
    return list;
}
```

may i know how to **clear/refresh** cache for **query.ContactInfoList** when calling hibernatetemplate **saveupdate**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().evictQueries("query.ContactInfoList");
```

will clear that cache region. You can't manually refresh cached query data; cache region will be re-populated (if enabled) once the query runs again.

Comment: call this after  hiberanteTemplate.saveOrUpdate(contactLIst); hibernateTemplate.flush(); hibernateTempalte.getSessionFactory().evictQueries("query.ContactInfoLIst");  ? correct?

Comment: If you're calling `flush()` explicitly to synchronize the state between concurrent sessions then yes, you should evict right after `flush()`. This seems like a rather unusual scenario, though (plus you'd have to deal with 1st level cache too). Normally, calling `flush()` manually should be avoided; session will be flushed on commit - in that scenario you can evict queries just prior to that.